# Contar palabras en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Nnecesito realizar un programa que me cuente palabras, con los espacios que se dejan entre palabras ellas.

```
f=open('contar.txt','r') 
w=f.read()
f.close()
print(w)
n=0
for i in range(0,len(w)): 
    if w[i]==' ' and w[i+1]!='': 
    
        n=n+1 
print('existen' , len (n+1), 'palabrar')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El `range` debe ser así `range(0,len(w)-1)`

Comment: Una de las preguntas más duplicadas de la historia de SOes, si buscas python + index out of range verás docenas de preguntas con respuesta, y siempre es por lo mismo... siempre, todas y cada una de las veces, el index out of range es porque te has salido del rango de tu iterable. No hay otra, y la solución siempre es la misma, saber que si tienes 10 caracteres, no puedes recorrer 11. Por favor, antes de abrir una pregunta **usa el buscador**!

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

Tu problema está en el momento en que el bucle for llega a la ultima posición de la cadena. Por ejemplo cuando se alcanza la posición 15 de la frase `zanahoria rayada` (recuerda que Python empieza a contar desde 0).

En esta comparación `w[i+1]!=''` Le sumas 1 a la posición e intentas acceder a la posición 16 de la cadena, la cual no existe, ya que la palabra terminó en la posición 15.

De cualquier forma, esa comparación daría siempre verdadero, ya que una cadena de un solo carácter como la que devolvería el código `"zanahoria rayada"[10]` nunca va a ser igual a una cadena vacía.

Otra cosa, estás tratando de obtener el largo de un número, eso no tiene sentido y te dará un error.

#### Solución

Simplemente quita la comparación `w[i+1]!=''`. Y para evitar otro error futuro el len.

```
f=open('contar.txt','r') 
w=f.read()
f.close()
print(w)
n=0
for i in range(0,len(w)): 
    if w[i]==' ': 
    
        n=n+1 
print('existen' , n+1, 'palabrar')
```

#### Algunos problemas en la lógica del código

Lo que en realidad hace tu código es contar los espacios, no las palabras (lo que parece que ya sabes). El problema de esto está en la frase que estás probando, pues esta tiene varios espacios seguidos. Estos espacios se sumarán a la cuenta dándote 13, y como le sumas 1, te dirá que hay 14 palabras, cuando en realidad hay solo 4 palabras.

Yo replantearía la idea. Te lo dejo de tarea ;)

Comment: Pregunta. Es un ejercicio de clase?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que el programa lee un archivo de texto. ¿Qué pasa si ese archivo tiene saltos de línea o tabulaciones? Hay que considerar esas opciones.

En el siguiente código, se recorre caracter por caracter y:

- si el caracter NO está en lista de separadores (`elif`), entonces se acumula en la variable word.
- Si el caracter es un separador y la variable `word` contiene una palabra (primer `if`) entonces se cuenta la palabra y se reinicia la variable `word`.
- [!] Si word está vacio y el caracter es un separador, no hacer nada. No se escribió.
- Finalmente, después que termina el ciclo `for`, si el texto termina en palabra, es posible que al final no tenga un separador, por lo que hay que agregarla al contador.

Entonces, el código optimizado para un archivo de texto multilínea sería:

```py
f=open('contar.txt','r') 
w=f.read()
f.close()

n = 0
word = ''
for character in w: 
    found_sep = character in [' ', '\r\n', '\n', '\t']
    if found_sep and word != '':
        # Cuando hay un espacio o salto y word tiene una palabra
        n += 1
        word = ''
    elif not found_sep:
        word += character
    # else: -> Cuando son varios espacios o saltos seguidos, no hacer nada
if word:
    # La última palabra no se contabiliza, entonces agregarla.
    n += 1

print('existen' , n, 'palabras')
```

---

Una mejora puede ser en vez de acumular la palabra en `word`, simplemente usar `True` y `False`. Además, convertirlo en una función para que esté disponible en cualquier momento:

```py
def contar_palabras(text):
    n = 0
    word = False
    for character in text:
        found_sep = character in [' ', '\r\n', '\n', '\t']
        if found_sep and word:
            n += 1
            word = False
        elif not found_sep:
            word = True
    return n+1 if word else n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Funcion Split

Sabiendo que quieres contar palabras, puedes hacer un sistema de contar palabras, basandose en un string

```
stre = "Contaremos palabras de Este String"
stre = stre.split(" ") # Esto hace una lista, con cada palabra, osea ["Contaremos","palabras","de","Este","String"]
numero = len(stre) # la funcion len() cuenta cada elemento en una lista, osea, hay 5 palabras en el string, por lo cual, 5 elementos en la lista, por lo cual, len(stre) va a devolver el numero 5
```

Los comentarios explican que hace la funcion

el .split que hay en el string, es para separar el texto en una lista, por ejemplo:

```
"hola/mundo/ /como/estas".split("/") # Eso separara el texto basandose en el caracter "/", devolveria ["hola","mundo"," ","como","estas"]
```